# How to get different unsat cores when using z3 on logic QF_LRA

Tags: z3

I am using z3 to extract the unsat core of an unsatisfiable linear constraint set. I find z3 may give a different unsat core for the same problem when setting the "auto-config" option to false. 
Does there exist other options which may make z3 give a different unsat core for the same problem?

Here is my previous related question: [How to get multiple different unsat cores or make the core smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378559/how-to-get-multiple-different-unsat-cores-or-make-the-core-smaller-with-z3-qf-l)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no specific API for getting different unsatisfiable cores, 
but you can use the existing API to retrieve some or all minimal cores. 
The following tutorial

http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/musmss

illustrates in a simplified way how to retrieve multiple cores (or all) and multiple maximal satisfying sets (or all) at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your superb answer!