# How to get z3 to return multiple unsat cores, multiple satisfying assignments

Tags: z3, smt, sat

I am working on a component of a research tool; 
I am interested in retrieving (for QF_LRA)

-multiple (minimal or otherwise) UNSAT cores and
-multiple SAT assignments

I have checked the forum for earlier discussions on this topic e.g.,
[How to get different unsat cores when using z3 on logic QF_LRA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299645/how-to-get-different-unsat-cores-when-using-z3-on-logic-qf-lra)

They refer to the z3 Python tutorial(s)
e.g, http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/musmss

which seems to be offline for now. I have tried other suggestions of github etc to find the mentioned tutorial, but have had no luck.

I am using the z3 Java API; but happy to switch to alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the tutorial. You can find more information on MARCO 
from Mark Liffiton's web pages.

## Enumeration of Minimal Unsatisfiable Cores and Maximal Satisfying Subsets

This tutorial illustrates how to use Z3 for extracting all minimal unsatisfiable cores
together with all maximal satisfying subsets.

### Origin

The algorithm that we describe next 
represents the essence of the core extraction procedure by Liffiton and Malik and independently 
by Previti and Marques-Silva:

Enumerating Infeasibility: Finding Multiple MUSes Quickly
Mark H. Liffiton and Ammar Malik
in *Proc. 10<sup>th</sup> International Conference on Integration of Artificial 
Intelligence (AI) and Operations Research (OR) techniques in Constraint Programming* (CPAIOR-2013), 160-175, May 2013.

Partial MUS Enumeration
Alessandro Previti, Joao Marques-Silva
in *Proc. AAAI-2013* July 2013

### Z3py Features

This implementation contains no tuning. 
It was contributed by Mark Liffiton and it is a simplification of one of the versions available from
his Marco Polo Web site. 
Code for eMUS is also available.
The example illustrates the following features of Z3's Python-based API:

1. Using assumptions to track unsatisfiable cores.

   Using multiple solvers and passing constraints between them.

   Calling the C-based API from Python. Not all API functions are supported over the Python 
   wrappers. This example shows how to get a unique integer identifier of an AST, 
   which can be used as a key in a hash-table.

### Idea of the Algorithm

The main idea of the algorithm is to maintain two 
logical contexts and exchange information between them:

1. The *MapSolver* is used to enumerate sets of clauses that are not already
   supersets of an existing unsatisfiable core and not already a subset of a maximal satisfying assignment.
   The *MapSolver* uses one unique atomic predicate per *soft* clause, so it enumerates
   sets of atomic predicates. For each minimal unsatisfiable core, say, represented by predicates
   *p<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>2</sub>, p<sub>5</sub>*, the *MapSolver* contains the 
   clause  *¬ p<sub>1</sub> ∨ ¬ p<sub>2</sub> ∨ ¬ p<sub>5</sub>*.
   For each maximal satisfiable subset, say, represented by predicats
   *p<sub>2</sub>, p<sub>3</sub>, p<sub>5</sub>*, the 
   *MapSolver* contains a clause corresponding to the disjunction of all literals
   not in the maximal satisfiable subset, *p<sub>1</sub> ∨ p<sub>4</sub> ∨ p<sub>6</sub>*.

   The *SubsetSolver* contains a set
   of soft clauses (clauses with the unique indicator atom occurring negated).
   The *MapSolver* feeds it a set of clauses (the indicator atoms).
   Recall that these are not already a superset of an existing minimal
   unsatisfiable core, or a subset of a maximal satisfying assignment. 
   If asserting these atoms makes the *SubsetSolver* context infeasible, 
   then it finds a minimal unsatisfiable subset corresponding to these atoms.
   If asserting the atoms is consistent with the *SubsetSolver*, then 
   it extends this set of atoms maximally to a satisfying set.

```
from Z3 import *

def main():
    x, y = Reals('x y')
    constraints = [x > 2, x < 1, x < 0, Or(x + y > 0, y < 0), Or(y >= 0, x >= 0), Or(y < 0, x < 0), Or(y > 0, x < 0)]
    csolver = SubsetSolver(constraints)
    msolver = MapSolver(n=csolver.n)
    for orig, lits in enumerate_sets(csolver, msolver):
        output = "%s %s" % (orig, lits)
        print(output)



def get_id(x):
    return Z3_get_ast_id(x.ctx.ref(),x.as_ast())

def MkOr(clause):
    if clause == []:
       return False
    else:
       return Or(clause)
```

SubsetSolver:

```
class SubsetSolver:
   constraints = []
   n = 0
   s = Solver()
   varcache = {}
   idcache = {}

   def __init__(self, constraints):
       self.constraints = constraints
       self.n = len(constraints)
       for i in range(self.n):
           self.s.add(Implies(self.c_var(i), constraints[i]))

   def c_var(self, i):
       if i not in self.varcache:
          v = Bool(str(self.constraints[abs(i)]))
          self.idcache[get_id(v)] = abs(i)
          if i >= 0:
             self.varcache[i] = v
          else:
             self.varcache[i] = Not(v)
       return self.varcache[i]

   def check_subset(self, seed):
       assumptions = self.to_c_lits(seed)
       return (self.s.check(assumptions) == sat)

   def to_c_lits(self, seed):
       return [self.c_var(i) for i in seed]

   def complement(self, aset):
       return set(range(self.n)).difference(aset)

   def seed_from_core(self):
       core = self.s.unsat_core()
       return [self.idcache[get_id(x)] for x in core]

   def shrink(self, seed):       
       current = set(seed)
       for i in seed:
          if i not in current:
             continue
          current.remove(i)
          if not self.check_subset(current):
             current = set(self.seed_from_core())
          else:
             current.add(i)
       return current

   def grow(self, seed):
       current = seed
       for i in self.complement(current):
           current.append(i)
           if not self.check_subset(current):
              current.pop()
       return current
```

MapSolver:

```
class MapSolver:
    def __init__(self, n):
        """Initialization.
           Args:
            n: The number of constraints to map.
        """
       self.solver = Solver()
       self.n = n
       self.all_n = set(range(n))  # used in complement fairly frequently

   def next_seed(self):
       """Get the seed from the current model, if there is one. 
            Returns:
            A seed as an array of 0-based constraint indexes.
       """
       if self.solver.check() == unsat:
            return None
       seed = self.all_n.copy()  # default to all True for "high bias"
       model = self.solver.model()
       for x in model:
           if is_false(model[x]):
              seed.remove(int(x.name()))
       return list(seed)

   def complement(self, aset):
       """Return the complement of a given set w.r.t. the set of mapped constraints."""
       return self.all_n.difference(aset)

   def block_down(self, frompoint):
       """Block down from a given set."""
       comp = self.complement(frompoint)
       self.solver.add( MkOr( [Bool(str(i)) for i in comp] ) )

   def block_up(self, frompoint):
       """Block up from a given set."""
       self.solver.add( MkOr( [Not(Bool(str(i))) for i in frompoint] ) )



  def enumerate_sets(csolver, map):
      """Basic MUS/MCS enumeration, as a simple example."""
      while True:
        seed = map.next_seed()
        if seed is None:
           return
        if csolver.check_subset(seed):
           MSS = csolver.grow(seed)
           yield ("MSS", csolver.to_c_lits(MSS))
           map.block_down(MSS)
        else:
           MUS = csolver.shrink(seed)
           yield ("MUS", csolver.to_c_lits(MUS))
           map.block_up(MUS)

   main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response and the pointer to Mark Liffiton's webpage.

Comment: Sorry, is there something missing in lines 3,4 in the code fragment above?