# z3 UNSAT, how to retrieve multiple cores

Tags: z3, smt, sat

Sorry to repost this question,
[How to get z3 to return multiple unsat cores, multiple satisfying assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732702/how-to-get-z3-to-return-multiple-unsat-cores-multiple-satisfying-assignments?answertab=active#tab-top)

For the sake of completeness, the original question from the link above was:

> I am interested in retrieving (for QF_LRA)
>
> -multiple (minimal or otherwise) UNSAT cores and
>   -multiple SAT assignments
>
> I have checked the forum for earlier discussions on this topic e.g.,
>   How to get different unsat cores when using z3 on logic QF_LRA. These
>   refer to the z3 Python tutorial(s) e.g,
>   http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/musmss which seems to be offline for
>   now. I have tried other suggestions of github etc to find the
>   mentioned tutorial, but have had no luck.

Thanks to Nikolaj Bjorner for posting an answer to my earlier question.
However, I am not sure if the code fragment posted in the answer is complete? Can someone comment on this?

I have looked up the referred papers and Mark Liffiton's webpages, referred in the answer to my original question. It would be most helpful if the complete code fragment can be reposted or clarified.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was a formatting problem: the HTML formatting cropped some characters. It has been fixed now. You should now see the entire example.